# Magento 2: Email Template error

Tags: email-templates, magento-2.1.7

I have a problem with my email templates. Whenever I fill out the form and it will take me to the success page. This will be the message in the email from my inbox.

By the way. It is a custom form with an array of data.

[image]

Thanks, Just correct me if I'm wrong with my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a error in your variables which you are passing to the template. Try to print the variables before passing it to template.

Comment: Hi @Abhinav so that's the reason why it is showing that error right? Ok I will try printing all the variables just to be sure. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I have now fixed the issue. It turned out that one of my variables is passing invalid characters. I followed your instructions to print every variable and it worked great. Thanks again